# Two app folders in one project on Android Studio using React Native

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Can anyone tell me what I have done to have my app folder outside of the Android root folder in Android Studio?

This is causing issues and I want the /app folder under the /Android folder to be the app.

Here is a screenshot of my directories:

[image]

Any help to point the correct folder as my app would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

So, I can answer my own question here - might be useful for anyone else having this issue.

It is because I imported my project into Android Studio at the root level.

i.e. /my-application-name

IMPORTANT: you must import the 'android' directory into android studio only

i.e. /my-application-name/android

I re-imported the 'android' directory of my project and that fixed the issue.

Hope this helps someone else who stumbles upon this issue.